# Debugging Symfony 2.x using Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, debugging, symfony

I'm looking for a good way to debug the Symfony 2.x bundles.
I have experience debugging php, but can't seem to set off with Symfony.

I use Eclipse Juno with Symfony support pluged in. (Windows 7 - 64 bit)

Comment: Are you debugging on a remote server or local server? Are you trying to debug a web app or command built on Symfony?

Comment: I'm trying to debug a web app, I'm not able to configure the debug session as the symfony tab doesn't seem to find available routes.
The server runs on the same machine (localhost)

Comment: You should not be doing anything differently from debugging a standard PHP project. Follow [this](http://www.fieg.nl/setting-up-xdebug-for-eclipse) for the specifics of setup, but the main point here is that you want to set up your URI as something like `http://localhost/code/web/app_dev.php/myroute/`